# jpa Embeddables inheritence from MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Is it possible for Embeddables  to inherit Basic , Transient , OneToOne etc attributes from MappedSuperClass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A `MappedSuperClass` designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the **entities** that inherit from it. `Embeddable`s are not entities.

Also, The JPA specification does not define inheritance for `Embeddable` objects

The EclipseLink JPA implementation does support inheritance for embeddables (see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Inheritance) for details). Of course, using this functionality is not be portable across JPA implementations.

Comment: So , Can Embeddables inherit property from Embeddables ?

Comment: he JPA specification does not define inheritance for embeddables, however it seems that the EclipseLink JPA implementation does support it (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Inheritance). Be warned using such a feature is not portable.